# Bootstrap modal opens automatically on page load, but how to disable if form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

I have a newsletter modal setup, which works fine. I have it set to launch automatically on page load via some javascript code, but how could I make it so that it doesn't open if you successfully submitted the form inside the modal?

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('#newsletter-modal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

HTML Modal Code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="newsletter-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content primary-modal">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text primary-modal-icon"></i> Subscribe to our Newsletter</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="color: #fff;">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body primary-modal-body">
          <form method="post" action="">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 primary-modal-form">
                    <label class="justify-content-center" style="color: rgba(255,255,255,.55); text-align: center;">Your Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="John Doe" name="newsletter_name">
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 primary-modal-form">
                    <label style="color: rgba(255,255,255,.55); text-align: center;">Your Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="johndoe123@gmail.com" name="newsletter_email">
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default swalDefaultSuccess" name="signup_newsletter">Subscribe <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right primary-modal-subscribe-icon"></i></button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `cookie` to store user information, such as passing some advertising campaign details or passed newsletter submission. Take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Is there any other way? I am not at all familiar with cookies, and I could learn but if there is another way that could be better

Comment: Other ways are more advanced and require deep knowledge.

Comment: cookie is the best bet

Comment: Oh alright, thanks friends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this it will help you:

[Dismiss Bootstrap Modal (Forever!) with jQuery Cookie, On Click](https://coderwall.com/p/gnqdpg/dismiss-bootstrap-modal-forever-with-jquery-cookie-on-click)

Comment: Thanks man! That's exactly what I needed :)

Comment: I set that up two ways and it didn't work. The cookie creates, but the modal doesn't open. If I removed the if statement around the modal it does, but with it the modal doesn't show: https://pastebin.com/pJ0dV6m5

Answer (score 0):

By doing it in PHP you prevent people from mucking about with the JS which is 'client-side'.

Additionally, you can only set the cookie if the subscribe works, ie after you've validated the email etc.

On the page PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['newsletter_email'])) {
   //you subscribe stuff here
   $_SESSION['subscribed']=true;
}
```

then wrap your modal js in

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['subscribed']))  {
    ///output your onload js.
}
```

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if it's proved useful and answered your question.

Comment: Oh right, thanks for the reminder. Kinda new to this site xD

Comment: For some reason that actually didn't work